# How to check with different table and update it in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a query that accomplishes to these rules:

- read records `(where CreatedDate = 06/06/2022 AND Status = Processed)` from Daily_Proc table.
- check if any particular record is also existed in *Lit_Hold_Err* table using "*MID*" and "*Source*" columns value.
- if a particular record is existed in *Lit_Hold_Err* table then update *Status* from "*Processed*" to "*Error-Retry*" in *Daily_Proc* table.

I'm able to do the first step and second step but not sure how to do step 3.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Daily_Proc
WHERE CreatedDate > '06/06/2022 0:00:00'
  AND Status = 'Processed'
  AND (MID in (SELECT MID
               FROM Lit_Hold_Err)
  AND Source In(Select Source
                From Lit_Hold_Err))
```

**Daily_Proc** table:

| Hold | MID | Source | CreateDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JE | JELEEK | JELEEK@gmail.com | 06/03/2022 | New |
| KE | KEKELO | KEKELO@gmail.com | 06/06/2022 | Processed |
| ZE | ZEKEKE | ZEKEKE@gmail.com | 06/06/2022 | Processed |

**Lit_Hold_Err** table:

| Hold | MID | Source | ErrorMessage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KE | KEKELO | KEKELO@gmail.com | "Not Found |

Comment: Use an stored procedure or an ETL; which way are you familiar with?

Comment: [Last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72520590/how-to-check-with-other-table-in-sql-server) you asked this about SQL Server 2008, now it's SQL Server 2012.  Are you sure which version you're using?  Whereas I don't think it's going to make a difference here, it is often the case where solutions differ between different versions.  If you just tagged a newer version because you got some comments about upgrading from SQL Server 2008, you may want to reconsider that.

Comment: @Hackerman Hi, I'm new to SQL Server so not really sure but I think Stored Procedure since I'm using Azure Data Studio to the query and write script.

Comment: @squillman I just check and it's SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I think you can easily do this with a simple `update` statement.

Comment: hi @shawnt00 could you please show me how in the Answer below?

Comment: Don't delete a question and reask it... There is an [edit] feature to correct or improve your question.

Comment: @Larnu ooh ok, sorry I didn't aware of that. I'll do that next time. thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to build your `UPDATE` statement using a `JOIN` operation, that matches the two tables *Daily_Proc* and *Lit_Hold_Err* on the *MID* and *Source* columns shared by both. Other conditions on *DailyProc.CreatedDate* and *DailyProc.Status* can be positioned inside the `WHERE` statement.

```
UPDATE Daily_Proc 
SET Status = 'Error-Retry'
FROM       Daily_Proc 
INNER JOIN Lit_Hold_Err
        ON Daily_Proc.MID = Lit_Hold_Err.MID
       AND Daily_Proc.Source = Lit_Hold_Err.Source
WHERE Daily_Proc.CreatedDate = '06/06/2022' 
  AND Daily_Proc.Status = 'Processed';
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=47a83a64bdfa73677cfb2f3f151c6e5a).

Comment: If you've learnt something new today, it was worth for me.